# priority to index.html for index.php in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i am trying to set the priority of `index.php` to `index.html` **(but just for landing page)** in my .htaccess file that works fine

but for `?page_id=16` its also display the same index.html page that i don't want

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

**NOTE:** i am using wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That does not solve the problem. "index.html" does not appear in the requested URL.

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer. I didn't understand very well. Sorry. Is it good ?

Comment: And now what about the file `index.html` that should get served as the homepage? :)

Comment: Sorry again. I forgot to add the DirectoryIndex rule.

Comment: but this can't helped me the same index.html page i see if i visited on `?page_id=16` page :(

Comment: @LucasWillems now i get 500 internal server error on both side means on `/` visit and on `?page_id=16` visit

Comment: I edited my answer again. I'm sorry to do these errors. I edit too quickly. Sorry. Now, I thinks it's good.

Comment: @LucasWillems no need to sorry, i am happy you are helping me, but now the same index.html views i get on both visits :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33634/discussion-between-jogesh-pi-and-lucas-willems)

Answer (score 0):

If you define via DirectoryIndex that the server should deliver `index.html` if it is there, and you access the url `/?page_id=16`, then `index.html` with that parameter is delivered. And the parameter does nothing - it's static HTML.

You cannot use BOTH `index.html` and `index.php` as DirectoryIndex for `/` and expect it to work.

Add code to `index.php` that returns the content of `index.html` if no parameter is given. `readfile('index.html'); exit();` might be enough. Only use `index.php` as DirectoryIndex.